# Performance: if (i == 0) versus if (!i)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I'm writing (or at least trying to write) some high-performance C++ code. I've come across a a part where I need to do a large amount of integer comparisons, namely, to check if the result is equal to zero.

Which is more efficient? That is, which requires fewer processor instructions?

```
if (i == 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
if (!i) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm running it on an x86-64 architecture, if that makes any difference.

Comment: no difference on a decent compiler.

Comment: Did you consider profiling the code (or even having a look at the actual assembly output), before asking here?

Comment: I'd expect that there is no difference on any decent compiler [at least, when optimizations are enabled] but I would also run some benchmarks to verify.

Comment: Why not make your question about those integer comparisons rather than something that appears to be rather trivial?

Comment: I'd personally say the `if (!i)` is more efficient. This is because when the compiler converts the code into machine-code this expression will use less memory than the former.

Comment: To quote the great [Paul R](http://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r). "Just worry about writing clear, concise, robust and reliable code - worrying about tiny micro-optimisations such as this is counter-productive and pointless."

Comment: I have not profiled the code (I've never profiled C++ code before). This is the integer comparison I am referring to; comparing it to `0`.

Comment: @FredrikPihl I guess you've got a point. =]

Comment: For the amount of people downvoting me, this question has gotten an disproportionate number of responses...

Comment: Voting to reopen, I don't see how this is off-topic, definitely not unclear what is being asked. Perhaps there is a duplicate of this question out there though. I also don't see why it received so many downvotes either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at the assembly (with no optimizations) of this code with gcc :

```
void foo(int& i)
{
  if(!i)
    i++;
}

void bar(int& i)
{
   if(i == 0)
     i++;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  foo(i);
  bar(i);
}
```

---

```
foo(int&):                               # @foo(int&)
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rsp)
    movq    -8(%rsp), %rdi
    cmpl    $0, (%rdi)
    jne .LBB0_2
    movq    -8(%rsp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %ecx
    addl    $1, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rax)
.LBB0_2:
    ret

bar(int&):                               # @bar(int&)
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rsp)
    movq    -8(%rsp), %rdi
    cmpl    $0, (%rdi)
    jne .LBB1_2
    movq    -8(%rsp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %ecx
    addl    $1, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rax)
.LBB1_2:
    ret

main:                                   # @main
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    callq   foo(int&)
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   bar(int&)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

---

**Bottom line:**

The generated assembly is exactly identical (even without optimizations enabled), so it doesn't matter : choose the clearer, most readable syntax, which is probably `if( i == 0)` in your case.

In C++, you almost never need to care about such micro optimizations, compilers/optimizers are very good at this game : trust them. If you don't and if you have a performance bottleneck, profile / look at the assembly for your particular platform.

**Note:**

- You can use [godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) to generate such assembly, it is a very handy tool.
- You can also use the -S option on gcc to produce the assembly (other compilers have similar options)

Comment: OP states "I've never profiled C++ code before", so perhaps add how you generated the output?

Comment: @FredrikPihl added as a note

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an insane compiler, they should compile identically. Having said that, for the sanity of future people looking at your code, only use `i == 0` if `i` is a numeric type and `!i` if `i` is a `bool` type.

Comment: If we go with how the computer actually works, the expression `if (!i)` is more efficient as the processor will need to do less with it (this strays a little into the CS [computer science] area, but however I thought I'd mention it).

Comment: "how the computer actually works...as the processor will need to do less with it" - please explain. All processors that I've personally programmed on (and I've done quite a bit of asm) have no advantage since, under the hood, the comparison for `bool`s is to compare against zero, exactly the same as `i==0`.

Comment: Now I've thought about that, it's true.

Answer (score 0):

No compiler of the better known ones will compile those to anything that differs significantly enough that it will matter when you do what everyone must do before applying manual optimizations: measure.